firebase functions (python) - how do I define a trigger function that adds a specific field to a new created document
I have a flutter flow app that authenticates users using google provider.
I am trying to set a firebase trigger function that will add the boolean field "isMoreInfoRequired",let it equal to true, and add it to the new created document.
Using Gemini, I've created a function that looks like this:

@on_document_created(document="users/{userId}")
def onUserCreated(event: Event[DocumentSnapshot]) -> None:
  new_value = event.data.to_dict()
  userId = new_value.id
  if "isMoreInfoNeeded" not in new_value:  # Check if property exists
    new_value["isMoreInfoNeeded"] = True
  # Update the document with the modified data
  db = firestore.client()
  doc_ref = db.collection("users").document(userId)
  doc_ref.set(new_value)


The function is deployed properly but it doesn't add the field at all.
Anyone knows how to make this function work?
I expected the document to have the "isMoreInfoRequired" field in addition to the other fields of the new document

What does the function actually do, if not what you expect?  Please edit the question to share what you've done to debug this so far, including any logs that help explain what is happening.  Your question should also explain what exactly you are doing to trigger the function.  We should be able to take your code and instructions and duplicate the same result for ourselves.

the functions is supposed to be triggered by any document creation and add it a boolean field which looks like "isMoreInfoRequired" which is set to true.
I managed to solve it by changing the functions programming language to javascript and wrote pretty much the same code.

Right, I understand what you want to happen, but your question as stated gives no instruction on what you're actually doing.  We can't tell if you've done something wrong at some point that affects the outcome.  We also can't see your logs to see if something failed.  Your question really should have those details in order to get good help.

If you've abandoned this code because you did something completely different, and you're not interesting in figuring out what's wrong, then please consider deleting the question entirely.

The problem is that new_value.id isn't the correct way to get the userId. Instead, you should use event.reference.id to get the document ID.

Hi thanks. unfortunately it didn't help. There weren't any errors but the it was either not triggered or not properly functioning. I managed to write the same function in js and it worked.
